# Using split to store information from .txt file into array

Tags: java, arrays, file, split

I have a file called `log.txt` (in same directory as the program), and it contains data which I want to split based on `.` and store it into `String[] plan`.

e.g., The `log.txt` contains a string like `332 445.114 554.963 342.` and so on...

What I want is to split it in such a way so that:

```
plan[0]=332 445;
plan[1]=114 554;
plan[2]=963 342;
```

And so on...

Comment: Did you try to do something? Maybe read split documentation, how to read a file line by line etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that `split()` uses regex, so you need to escape `.`: `split("\\.")`.

Comment: Please bare with me @Marco ,i'm new to java...i have a log.txt, that contains:332 445.114 554.963 342. and so on... What i need is: plan[0]=332 445;plan[1]=114 554;plan[2]=963 342; tnx.

Comment: Example input and expected output are good, but please include your current attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
String[] plan = (new Scanner( new File("log.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next()).split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

This line saves lines from file into an array of String.

Is it okay for you?

Edit: Here is what you might be looking for...

```
String[] plan = (new Scanner( new File("log.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next()).split("\\.");
```

Comment: The log.txt contains: 332 445.114 554.963 342. and so on... What i need is: plan[0]=332 445;plan[1]=114 554;plan[2]=963 342; THANKS @tod!

Comment: Well, here you go:
`String[] plan = (new Scanner( new File("log.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next()).split("\\.");`